# QGIS 3.12 raster reprojection giving no result

Tags: qgis, raster, dem

I would like to reproject my raster DEM from the EPSG:4376 (WGS-84) to the EPSG:27700 (British National Grid 1936). When I use the option: Raster -> Translate (COnvert format), as shown below:

[image]

Everything proceeds alright, which finishes the comment: 
**"Algorithm 'Translate (convert format)' finished"**

Unfortunately, it's not translated into the visual result, because the layer is completely transparent.

[image]

Further saving the layer as a .TIFF format doesn't help.

What am I doing wrong here then?

Comment: Instead of using the Translate tool, I'd just right click on the original layer, export as, choose tif and the projection you want it to be saved in.

Comment: What you did makes QGIS to run gdal_translate https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_translate.html with option "assign srs" `-a_srs`. That option is for adding SRS into image that does not have any, or fixing the info if it is wrong. The image data remains untouched so no warping will happen. Use the Export - Save as instead.

Comment: You can try with raster/projection/Warp(reproject)

Comment: I know that. Just wondering, why the 2nd option is not working properly.